# How to handle Socket Exception

Tags: c#, sockets

```
Socket tempSocket;
try
{
    IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint endpt = new IPEndPoint(addr, port);
    tempSocket = new Socket(endpt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    tempSocket.Connect(endpt);
}
catch
{
    OnDisconnected("Connection Error");
    return false;
}
```

My console program keeps crashing with the error message saying that there is a socket exception because the target machine actively refused the connection. This is fine, since sometimes the other end is not running, which would be normal. My question is, how do I properly handle this so that the program doesnt crash, and instead just returns False? I tried googling for this, but could not find anything. 
[image]

Comment: try this 
 `catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }`

Comment: Same issue, doesn't seem to actually hit the catch block.

Comment: It seems that you are on `break on all exceptions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program will already not "crash" with the code you showed; i.e. if you catch the exception and return false from your function.

The window you see ("Exception Assistant") is optional to help you with debugging, it will not be shown if you run your program outside of the Visual Studio, or turn off option to always break into code on any exception. It can be configured in Debug => Exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to catch the socket exception and return false.

```
catch (SocketException e) 
{
 return false;
}
```

Your code will be something like this

```
Socket tempSocket;
try
{
    IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint endpt = new IPEndPoint(addr, port);
    tempSocket = new Socket(endpt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    tempSocket.Connect(endpt);
}
catch (SocketException e) 
{
    OnDisconnected("Connection Error");
    return false;
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    OnDisconnected("any other exception Error");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you aren't going to do anything with the exceptions why not get rid of the exception variables like catch(SocketException){ OnDisconnected("Connection Error"); return false } catch(Exception) { OnDisconnected("any other exception Error"); return false; }

Answer (score 0):

Change you exception handling setting in Visual Studio for Socket exception. Go to DEBUG -> Exception..., find System.Net.Sockets.SocketException and deselect Thrown.

[image]

More information can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Of course, you will not have this issue when you run your application outside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex) 
{ 
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

or

```
   Socket tempSocket;
   IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
   IPEndPoint endpt = new IPEndPoint(addr, port);
   using (tempSocket = new Socket(endpt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                tempSocket.Connect(endpt);
            }
```

Comment: "Try this" - why? What do you think is the problem, and how does this code fix that?